# Are Neo generators a Scam or not?

Tags: generator, energy

After reading the [FAQ page of Neo generators](http://neo.sx/preguntas-neo.html), I became incredulous of this particular part (translated from Spanish):

> HOW DOES IT WORK INTERNALLY?
>
> Our optimized system collects the
>   abundant radiant energy from the atmosphere and the system is excited
>   using a plasma reactor also manufactured by NEO. The ensemble performs
>   the operation to capture the radiant and it is magnified by the
>   reactor. The key part or element of our system is the reactor and it
>   is the element that after its utility life deteriorates itself and
>   makes the system unusable.

Radiant energy of the atmosphere and excited trough a plasma reactor?!

And in the [patents page](http://neo.sx/patentes-neo.html) they say the utility life of 35 years! Is this believable?

By the way, the top-level domain (.sx) is at least strange!

The question is: Is the Neo generator a credible product?

Comment: I can't read the Spanish and pasting the URL into google translate appears to confuse it, but: it's a scam. "Revolutionary" generator products with technobabble are *always* a scam.

Comment: Sorry, this is an English only site. *You* should use a translation service before posting here. -1

Comment: I added English translation. Can you know undownvote the question? @pjc50

Comment: Someone has had fun drawing those plasma reactor pictures for the "patent" ;)

Comment: Actually, that page of patents are real patents - but patents held by various other people (two of them by "Mehran Keshe Tavakoli" from Iran). It looks like they have just gathered a selection of likely sounding patents together and advertised a "product" that could maybe in a parallel universe use them to generate "free", "revolutionary" power.

Comment: @sergiol - Thanks for translating the citation for us. I've removed my downvote.

Comment: One of those patents (left second row) is from Tesla in 1897.

Comment: I gotta give you thumbs up man, these things just make my days good again :)

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not relevant anymore, because the web page it refers ceased to exist.

Answer (score 5):

- **Looking at the hosting of the site and the site itself...**

We've got a **Dominican Republic** company with a **Sint Maarten** registered domain name using a **yahoo.com** email address advertising contact details for **Mexico**, **Panama** and **USA**.

All the legal information is generated on the fly by javascript and is held in the "legalneo_hype_container" div.

Does that sound really legitimate?  I think not.

- **Looking through the FAQ I find this little nugget:**

> CAN CONNECT MORE OF A GENERATOR IN PARALLEL?
>
> Yes, all models can be interconnected to add the power of all generators who wants to have connected simultaneously.

(bad translation thanks to gurgle).

So you can just take a bunch of 220V 50Hz generators and slap them in parallel can you? No phase or frequency matching needed? That's incredibly clever of them!  If that's the level of technical expertise they have then these really must be good... NOT!

Answer (score 5):

Ho ho! You might want to look closely at the patents page. I count two by Nicola Tesla, each more than 100 years old and therefor expired, a 1908 patent grant, a 2007 application which was obviously rejected on the basis of factual impossibility, and several others which are apparently illustrations lifted from applications with no description at all as to the source.

The 2007 EPA is particularly entertaining, calling for (in one version) the injection of sodium or potassium vapor between two layers of argon and neon, the entire gas flow surrounding a hydrogen layer - and the whole thing done in a package the size of a 9-volt battery.

As an exercise in techie fantasy, the whole thing is actually pretty impressive.

As an exercise in fraud, it's likewise pretty impressive, without the grudging admiration implied in the previous sentence.

Answer (score 1):

## It's a scam.

As pjc50 said, "Revolutionary" generators are always a scam.

The patents page does not look credible and the technical details are fuzzy. Don't trust such claims.